# How to update java from repository on Debian?

Tags: java, debian

I would like to ask you how to update java from our internal repos on Debian 8 (jessie).

Is it necessary to delete old java version (java-8-oracle-1.8.0.131)  and after that install new one?

Or run some apt-get comand for update to version 1.8.0.152?

Really thanks for help

Comment: it isn't necessary to delete old version.

Comment: ok so steps should be:
1 - sudo apt-get update
2 - sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-jre
- I guess that latest available java from repos will be installed. Am I Right?

Thanks

Comment: How to install using `apt-get` is a question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: if you have installed old version of jre, sudo apt-get update <package-name> should work. `man apt-get` also very usefull command.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was, just run apt-get update (update repo list) and apt-get upgrade, if java is installed from repo, automatically will update java to latest available version from repo.